# Unable to launch QTP on remote machine using vbs

Tags: qtp

'Tried doing the following:

'DCOM Configuration is done (on the machine where the script has to be run)

'Script resides in the Script Initiator machine:
Dim qtApp

Set qtApp = CreateObject("QuickTest.Application","ipaddress") 'Create the application object

WScript.sleep 2000

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
Wscript.Echo ("Error is :"&Err.Number&":" & Err.Description)
End IF
qtApp.Launch 'Start QuickTest

qtApp.Visible = True 'Make it visible

msgbox('Executed')

'Please Help.. 
'Even logged in with same user on both machines

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: Sometimes i receive vbscript error -2146233083 and sometimes it does not give any error and processes QTPAutomationagent.exe and UFT.exe get created and killed instantly.

Comment: Forget the vbscript to invoke QTP remotely. I would advise you to use Jenkins - http://www.testautomationguru.com/executing-qtpuft-scripts-using-jenkins/

Comment: I need to call this vbs from Team City. But it should itself work independently.